# implement a queue using two stacks

Tags: java, stack, queue

I think my codes are right, but i do not know why it is not adding elements onto the stack.
Should i create other two stacks in the main?

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class stacks {
    public Stack<Integer> in = new Stack<Integer>();
    public Stack<Integer> out = new Stack<Integer>();

    public void enqueue(int value){
         in.push(value);
    }
    public int dequeue(){
         if (out.isEmpty()){
            while(!in.isEmpty()){
                out.push(in.pop());
            }
        }
        return out.pop();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        in.enqueue(10);
        in.enqueue(49);


    }

}
```

Comment: How do you know it isn't adding elements to the stack?

Comment: More importantly, can you tell us _how_ this is supposed to be implementing a queue in terms of two stacks?  If you can tell us _how_ it's supposed to work, then people can start to point out where the _code_ diverges from the _intent_.

Comment: i am using the stack library in java

Comment: i got a red line under " in.enqueue(10)" and the other one in the main, and the error says "cannot make a static reference to the non-static field in"

Comment: I don't see how this is more efficient than just using an ArrayList

Comment: @Julius Probably school work

Comment: @user2892181 : I see an error in the dequeue method as well. I have mentioned it in the answer below. This is a good. Possible interview qn. Could you guyz also check whether I had catered to that problem in a correct manner or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is absolutely correct. You have missed one small thing.

You are pushing elements in `stack 1` during `enqueue`.
During `dequeue`, you are popping elements from `stack 1` and pushing in `stack 2`. Then you are popping the top element from `stack 2` .

(1).
The stuff that you are missing is. Popping all the elements back from stack 2 and pushing them to stack 1. So, here is what I suggest you to do :

```
public int dequeue(){
         if (out.isEmpty())
         {
          while(!in.isEmpty())
            {
                out.push(in.pop());
            }
          }
        int outVar = out.pop();
        while(!out.isEmpty())
            {
                in.push(out.pop());
            }
         return outVar;
    }
```

(2). In the main method. You do not have to create two different stacks. You just have to create an  object of you class `Stacks`. which would solve the purpose.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Stacks obj = new Stacks();
        obj.enqueue(10); // Would enqueue 10 in the Stack 1 of the Object 'obj'
        obj.enqueue(49);

        System.out.println(obj.dequeue());// Would display the dequeued element. 


    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @user2892181 : Kewl ! If you got the answer correct through this. Then accept this answer. If you are still confused please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is that you are trying to make a static reference (from the main) to something that isn't static.

Make the following changes:

`public static int dequeue()`

`public static void enqueue(int value)`

A workaround to this would be to make an object oriented stack-queue class and then in a separate class make an instance of that stack-queue class. This would eliminate any static referential issues and also bring your program up to par with today's common object-oriented programming standards. Like so:

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class stacksTest {
    public Stack<Integer> in = new Stack<Integer>();
    public Stack<Integer> out = new Stack<Integer>();

    public void enqueue(int value){
         in.push(value);
    }
    public int dequeue(){
         if (out.isEmpty()){
            while(!in.isEmpty()){
                out.push(in.pop());
            }
        }
        return out.pop();
    }
}
```

Then make a new class:

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    stackTest st = new stackTest();
    st.enqueue(10);
    st.dequeue(10);        
}
}
```

Comment: the problem is the enqueue method

Comment: @user2892181 Try approach 2, my first approach is a little more complicated than what I gave you.